# Comments produced by ng-repeat break first-child pseudo selector in IE8

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

It seems that in AngularJS 1.2.13 (and as far back as 1.0.8), the ng-repeat directive creates DOM comments around the repeated elements. This is breaking in IE8 because the first-child is not the element but the comment. Is there a way to suppress the comments in Angular or do they serve a higher purpose? I know I can put a first-child class based on $first in the directive, but I don't want to if I don't have to.

Thanks.

P.S.
I have all proper shims and polyfills and best practices in place otherwise.

**Update**

IE8 is acting like it is IE7 for some reason, which is triggering this issue. I am still digging into why that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came about when using [IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) as a shim, it was somehow making IE8 behave like IE7 rather than IE9, I reduced the ES5 shims down to the bare minimum and now things are working as expected.

Comment: _making IE8 behave like IE7_ - if you mean running it in Compatibility mode (the "broken page" icon next to url bar in IE) then you can 1) disable this manually in your browser (but the same can happen to any other user) 2) put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in your head 3) set your server to serve this header

Comment: I have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">` in the head. This was something very strange, my IE conditionals were even behaving like the browser was IE7 and not 8. I will try to create a fiddle to recreate it. If jsFiddle even works in IE8 reliably.